# CSS Circular Cropping of Rectangle Image

Tags: html, css

I want to make a centered circular image from rectangle photo.
The photo's dimensions is unknown. Usually it's a rectangle form.
I've tried a lot of methods:

**Code**

```css
.image-cropper {
    max-width: 100px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image-cropper img{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
    width: 150%; 
    margin: 0 0 0 -20%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;  
}
```

```html
<div class="image-cropper">
   <img src="https://sf1.autojournal.fr/wp-content/uploads/autojournal/2012/07/4503003e3c38bc818d635f5a52330d.jpg" class="rounded" />
</div>
```

Comment: i sit fine??? http://jsfiddle.net/7c9wjLy6/3/

Comment: Is there a reason you have margin specified twice with different values?

Comment: might want to correct the question with removing "Usually", if it is that then none of the css solutions wont cut it.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

The approach is wrong, you need to apply the `border-radius` to the container `div` instead of the actual image.

This would work:

```css
.image-cropper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

img {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-cropper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="rounded" />
</div>
```

Comment: Understood. But why image is not centered in the circle?

Comment: True. I think Hiral's solution better suits your needs, and the background-image can be fed dynamically by Wordpress with ease. For some reason I can't solve my solution with text-align: center; so I cant really help you with the centring at the moment :(

Comment: This solution does not work with images in landscape orientation.

Comment: @49volro if you want the image to be centered, giving it a margin-left of -25% will do the trick.

Comment: this makes the image lop sided

Answer (score 94):

The [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property provides a non-hackish way for doing this (with image centered).  It has been supported in major browsers for a few years now (Chrome/Safari since 2013, Firefox since 2015, and Edge since 2015) with the exception of Internet Explorer.

```css
img.rounded {
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="rounded">
```

Comment: Brilliant! I love this simple, one-step solution. I has to remove the `img` from the css you provided and add it as a class to the image, but it worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: This is great, thank you! Should be the accepted answer imo

Answer (score 23):

If you can live without the `<img>` tag, I suggest you use the photo as a background image.

```css
.cropcircle{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #eee no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}

#image1{
    background-image: url(http://www.voont.com/files/images/edit/7-ridiculous-ways-boost-self-esteem/happy.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div id="image1" class="cropcircle"></div>
```

Answer (score 15):

A simple one liner.

```
clip-path: circle();
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/13u5z2mg/)

OR:

```
.rounded {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background:url("http://www.electricvelocity.com.au/Upload/Blogs/smart-e-bike-side_2.jpg") center no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/13u5z2mg/2)

Comment: Your demo is not circular.

Comment: Nice, but I can't use `background-image` because image's URL will generate Wordpress. Can I write: `<div class="image-cropper">
    <img class="rounded" style="background:url('http://www.electricvelocity.com.au/Upload/Blogs/smart-e-bike-side_2.jpg') center no-repeat; background-size:cover;" />
</div>` ?

Comment: @49volro In such case you can write this: [<div class="rounded" style="background-image:url('image url')"></div>](http://jsfiddle.net/13u5z2mg/6/), remove image url from css

Comment: The example worked for me, except it blew up my image. It worked if I put the image inside a div tag and specified the image dimensions in the div.

Comment: what if you can't use as background image even though ur exampleis not circular it is oval

Comment: @AravindReddy, you can give as much radius as much required. 50% will make it round, however, you can give lesser as per requirements.

Comment: I would appreciate if persons who down voted left comments for the reason!

Answer (score 3):

Johnny's solution is good. I found that adding min-width:100%, really helps images fill the entire circle. You could do this with a combination of JavaScript to get optimal results or use ImageMagick - http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php if you're really serious about getting it right.

```css
.image-cropper {

  width: 35px;

  height: 35px;

  position: relative;

  overflow: hidden;

  border-radius: 50%;

}

.image-cropper__image {

  display: inline;

  margin: 0 auto;

  height: 100%;

  min-width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<div class="image-cropper">
  <img src="#" class="image-cropper__image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know many of the solutions mentioned above works, you can as well try flex.

But my image was rectangular and not fitting properly. so this is what i did.

```
.parentDivClass {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

and for the image inside, you can use,

```
child Img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

This is helpful when you are using bootstrap 4 classes.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've been able to do this is with using the new css `object-fit` (1) property and the `padding-bottom` (2)  hack.

You need a wrapper element around the image. You can use whatever you want, but I like using the new HTML `picture` tag.

```css
.rounded {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rounded img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}


/* These classes just used for demo */
.w25 {
  width: 25%;
}

.w50 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="w25">
<picture class="rounded">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/A8eQsll.jpg">
</picture>
</div>

<!-- example using a div -->
<div class="w50">
<div class="rounded">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/A8eQsll.jpg">
</div>
</div>

<picture class="rounded">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/A8eQsll.jpg">
</picture>
```

### References

1. [CSS Image size, how to fill, not stretch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757537/css-image-size-how-to-fill-not-stretch/29103071#29103071)
2. [Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer probably works for some situations, but it depends on the ratio of the rectangle and any predetermined styles.

I use this method because it's more compatible than solutions only using `object-fit`:

```css
.image-cropper {
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border:2px solid #f00;
}

/* Common img styles in web dev environments */
img {
   height: auto;
   max-width: 100%;
}

/* Center image inside of parent */
img.center {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* For horizontal rectangles */
img.horizontal {
   height: 100%;
   width: auto;
   max-width: 9999px; /* max-content fall back */
   max-width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-cropper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x600" class="center" />
</div>

<div class="image-cropper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300" class="horizontal center" />
</div>
```

If you run the snippet you can see, for horizontal rectangles we add another class `.horizontal`.

We override `max-width` to allow the img to go larger than 100% of the width. This preserves the aspect ratio, preventing the image from stretching.

However, the image will not be centered and that's where the `.centered` class comes in. It uses a great centering trick to absolute position the image in the center both vertically and horizontally.

[More information on the centering at CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

More than likely you won't always know what ratio the image will be, so this is why I'd suggest using javascript to target the img and add the `.horizontal` class if needed.

[Here is a stack overflow answer that would work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891467/how-to-calculate-whether-an-image-is-landscape-or-portrait)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.image-cropper {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 18px 2px rgba(8, 49, 150, 0.05);
}
.image-cropper img {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Add more details to your answer, at least you should explain how this works.

Answer (score 0):

just use object-fit with border-radius to your image directly:

```
.image-cropper img{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use jQuery to do this. This approach gives you the abbility to have dynamic images and do them round no matter the size.

My demo has one flaw right now I don't center the image in the container, but ill return to it in a minute (need to finish a script I'm working on).

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e6oLrop2/)

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="" class="image" alt="lambo" />
</div>

//script
var container = $('.container'),
    image = container.find('img');

container.width(image.height());


//css    
.container {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;    
}

.image {
    height: 100%;    
    display: block;    
}
```

Comment: Definitely don't need jQuery. See accepted answer or @Tom's

Comment: @abettermap those solution don't have dynamic height, if you read the question, "Usually it's a rectangle form." meaning not always, therefor I get the image height with javascript. Seo value is lost with Toms solution. So read and think best pracitce also before downvoting.

Comment: The answers using `background-image` have dynamic height in the sense that the image will fill the circular space regardless of what the height is, which I think was the OP's goal.

Re: best practices, I think some might argue that not using JS for styling would be best practice. You have a point with SEO, however, so I will edit your response. Feel free to edit further.

Comment: This "answer" should be deleted.

Comment: @reformed the answer was made in 2014 and css has evolved in the past 9 years, also care to motivate the "constructive feedback" as to why it should be deleted?

Comment: @Dejan.S 1) OP specifically requested CSS, not jQuery. 2) "You need to use jQuery to do this" is not true. 3) You admit your demo is flawed, and the -4 negative impact likely renders it not worth your time to "fix"/"finish" it.

Comment: @reformed Sure fair enough with the CSS, but, what all the answers fail to provide is the dynamic part as the OP clearly state that the dimensions are not known and usually a rectangle as in "not always". Read the comments to my answer here where I also bring up the SEO. Also keep in mind that my answer was made in 2014. As far as the "flaw part", many times giving a OP a hint the solution might come by itself. To be fair the OP never mention "has to be CSS", the lack of a tag does not mean the answer is gone be what someone thinks as they come here for answers to what they don't know right.

Comment: @Dejan.S Just FYI I didn't downvote you. I guess I would ask, if you, today, were faced with the same problem as the OP, would you go with the solution presented by this answer here, to solve it?

Answer (score -2):

insert the image and then backhand all you need is:

```
<style>
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
```

** the image code will be here automatically**

Comment: The OP wanted a "circle", your example is only rounding the edges, which if the image is rectangular, the result would be an oval.