# Image Placeholder for Broken Image Link?

Tags: php, html, css, image, placeholder

Currently users can upload images to my site, and the location of the image is stored in a MySQL table.

When I call the images with the SELECT function, they are loaded via the CSS Style **background-image:url('image.jpg')**

Currently I have used an IF statement that places a placeholder image in the place of any rows that have column "Image_URL" set to NULL.

```
if ($row["Image"] != "") {                  
                    echo "<td width='200' rowspan='3'><center><a href='/uploads/".$row["Image"]."' target='_blank'><div class='image-cropper'><div class='rounded' style='background-image:url(\"/uploads/".$row["Image"]."\")'>";
                } else {
                    echo "<td width='200' rowspan='3'><center><a><div class='image-cropper'><div class='rounded' style='background-image:url(\"/images/no-image.jpg\")'";
                }
```

My method, however, does not work for erroneous links (where the original image has been deleted, or, for some reason, the link is wrong.) It just shows blank, and I can see why, because **$row["Image"] != NULL**, there is a link there, it's just not linking to an image.

Is there a way to load my placeholder image no-image.jpg when no image is found at the provided link?

My DIVs are merely to make my images circular and centered, so I post them here in case it helps, you may be able to help me adapt these classes to add the placeholder functionality.

```
.image-cropper {
    max-width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.rounded {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background:center no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

The image-cropper and rounded DIV are actually from this site, so thank you to [Hiral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26421274/css-circular-cropping-of-rectangle-image)!

Comment: Can you tell what's the format of your pics? Are they all "jpg"? Or they can be different?

Comment: Hi Sina, they can be different, I set the upload form to only allow JPG, GIF, and PNG files.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to work using `file_exists` after stuggling to use `glob`.

But thank you to Stewartside for putting me on the right path, and also structuring the resulting `if` statement.

This is the code now:

```
$image = $row["Image"];
if ($row["Image"] != "") {  
    if (file_exists('uploads/'.$image)) {               
        echo "<td width='200' rowspan='3'><center><a href='/uploads/".$row["Image"]."' target='_blank'><div class='image-cropper'><div class='rounded' style='background-image:url(\"/uploads/".$row["Image"];
    } else {
        echo "<td width='200' rowspan='3'><center><a><div class='image-cropper'><div class='rounded' style='background-image:url(\"/images/no-image.jpg";
    }
    } else {
        echo "<td width='200' rowspan='3'><center><a><div class='image-cropper'><div class='rounded' style='background-image:url(\"/images/no-image.jpg";
}
```

I assume the following would also work:

```
    if (file_exists('uploads/'.$row["Image"])) {
```

Thank you for your help everyone! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `glob()` function to find out if the file exists.

Something along these lines:

```
if ($row["Image"] != "") {
  var $file = glob("/uploads/".$row["Image"]); 
  if (count($file) > 0) {
    echo "<td width='200' rowspan='3'><center><a href='/uploads/".$row["Image"]."' target='_blank'><div class='image-cropper'><div class='rounded' style='background-image:url(\"/uploads/".$row["Image"]."\")'>";
  } else {
    echo "<td width='200' rowspan='3'><center><a><div class='image-cropper'><div class='rounded' style='background-image:url(\"/images/no-image.jpg\")'";
  }
} else {
  echo "<td width='200' rowspan='3'><center><a><div class='image-cropper'><div class='rounded' style='background-image:url(\"/images/no-image.jpg\")'";
}
```

- [PHP Documentation - Glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)