# convert rectangular image into Round image

Tags: css, angularjs, image-clipping

My Objective is to make an image round and display it. If the image is square then i am able to convert it in to round by simply using `border-radius:50%`property of CSS. But when the image is rectangular then using this CSS property is giving me oval shaped image.

One solution i thought of is first converting a rectangular image into square by using `clip:rect(10px,0px,10px,0px)` property. By using this it is clipping image into square but not removing the clipped space. i.e. it is making that part invisible but image is still rectangular.[image: clipped part is invisible but taking space]

Clipped part is invisible but still there. So even now i am trying to use `border-radius:50%` property it is giving me oval image with right and left side clipped.

Is there any way that i can solve this?

Comment: maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26421274/css-circular-cropping-of-rectangle-image

Comment: @guergana wow!! tried every kind of image.. worked like a charm.. mistake i was doing is using these tags in my image tag instead of using it in its container tag.. thanks a lot.. wish i could give you some points but my reputation score won't allow me :| once again thank you so much

Comment: I am glad I could help!

Comment: I can mark it as the solution and you can mark it as the correct solution I guess

Comment: You can try this. *Following up form the comment* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26421274/css-circular-cropping-of-rectangle-image

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ Using this you can clip a particular part of the image which you want in circle.

```css
img {
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(50.0% at 50% 50%);
  clip-path: circle(50.0% at 50% 50%);
}


/* Center the demo */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSCZNdFX5bx4Y_s8H-StHpWx3ujpCsG3qxhIu_-57pqSq3wKPEbndqnmROl" />
```

Comment: @IshanKhanduja Glad to hear that. You can mark answered. :)

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem, But you will need to adjust width and height , image will be in center but you can adjust it using `background-position: center;`

```
<div style="margin-top:5%"> 
    <div style="height:200px;width:200px; margin: 5% auto;
         background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oImMD.png);
         background-repeat: no-repeat;    border-radius: 50%;
         border: 5px solid #fff;background-position: center;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes.. working with all kind of images :)
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad to help. :) Please mark the correct answer if issue is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `width` and `height` of the image and then apply `border-radius` to it.

Thus one way you could do is this

### Solution 1

```
.circle-img {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   border-radius: 50%;
}
```

However this might make some distortion on the circular image output you were expecting.
Thus what another way could be this

### Solution2

```
.circle-wrapper {
   height: 100px;
   circle: 100px;
   overflow: hidden;
   border-radius: 50%;
}
```

What happens here is that it will hide anything that exceeds the specification of 100x100 and makes the circular effect.

Comment: yes sir.. 2nd solution is perfect solution that i wanted :) Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @IshanKhanduja Please do mark as correct if it has solved your problem