# How can I make the image on title bar rounded?

Tags: html

I want to make the icon on title bar rounded, I have just a square but I'd like to make it rounded. Is it possible to do so or should I make the icon rounded manually?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Circular Cropping of Rectangle Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26421274/css-circular-cropping-of-rectangle-image)

Comment: I'm not really sure, I think it's not really what I want.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include sample HTML, plus any research and attempts you've made.

Answer (score 1):

I think so far, the best way to leave the icon look rounded next to the page title is editing the picture itself to look that way before importing it as an external resource on the .

Professional webpages leave the favicons rounded from what i noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Set the style of that icon to have `border-radius: 5px` or any radius you like.

Comment: It's not working... I think do something wrong. Is it possible to see an example?

Comment: Please edit your post to include sections of your code. It's hard for us to guess what you have tried and what went wrong. Hope you got your code fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about favicon that appears at the left side of title.

It is not possible to round the image there because it is an external resource to the `HTML`.

So, if you want that favicon to be rounded, you can use any image editor or any online tools mentioned below.

```
https://redketchup.io/favicon-generator
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer. I will edit the whole icon then.